# How to add external CSS while generating PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Currently i am using following code to generate PDF in a JSP file:

```
response.setContentType("application/force-download");                                                          
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=reports.pdf");                                                     
Document document = new Document();                                      
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A1);

PdfWriter writer = null;                                                      

writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());                                         

document.open();                                                                                   

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlSource.toString().getBytes());                                                                                      

XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, bis);                                                                   

document.close();
```

With this am able to generate PDF.

But i would like to add CSS file while generating PDF.

Please Help me...

Comment: Css file you want to add to give some styling to content inside your pdf? Or one more css file you want to create along with pdf file?

Answer (score 4):

i am not sure in java how can you use but in c# you can add external style sheet code or syntax by this code:-

```
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
    css.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "Garamond");
    css.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
    css.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "12pt");
```

may be this helps you

Regards,
vinit

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [ParseHtmlTable1](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-tables#965-parsehtmltable1.java) example. In this example, we have HTML stored in a `StringBuilder` object and some CSS stored in a `String`. In my example, I convert the `sb` object and the `CSS` object to an `InputStream`. If you have files with the HTML and the CSS, you could easily use a `FileInputStream`.

Once you have an `InputStream` for the HTML and the CSS, you can use this code:

```
// CSS
CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream(CSS.getBytes()));
cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

// HTML
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

// Pipelines
PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

// XML Worker
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes()));
```

Or, if you don't like all that code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlSource.toString().getBytes());  
ByteArrayInputStream cis = new ByteArrayInputStream(cssSource.toString().getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, bis, cis);
```

Comment: what about if you need to include an image on the pdf and the css is pointing to it?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code reference.

```
$html .= '<style>'.file_get_contents(_BASE_PATH.'stylesheet.css').'</style>';
```

Answer (score -3):

Change content type to

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: I want to download PDF. I am not writing output to browser.

Comment: @YellaGoud the standard bahavior for this content type is to ask the user for an action (open or download the dokument).

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explanations to your intention.